# What javascript objects have addEventlistener in their prototype?

Tags: javascript, events, prototype, addeventlistener

I know of the following:

```
Element.prototype.addEventListener
Window.prototype.addEventListener
Document.prototype.addEventListener
```

Any others?

Comment: http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Events/events.html

Comment: @Andreas I couldn't find a list on the w3c reference you linked to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One more: `XMLHttpRequest`

And anything in the prototype chain.

Comment: Andread gave you a good like with http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Events/events.html. MDN is always a good source as well:https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.addEventListener. It's basically any object that supports events.

Comment: Thanks! The MDN link was helpful.